# Escape a char which does not match a given regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to escape any single '{', '}' braces which do not match the pattern `\{\{(.*?)}}`. (i.e in `{{{abc}}` very first '{' should get escaped). Can someone please help me write a regex for this?

Comment: That means you want to escape those braces that do not match `\{\{[^{}]*}}` pattern. BTW, are there any escape sequences already in the string that should be taken care of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: *This will work in case you have no escape sequences in your input string.*

You may create a "wrapper" regex to match and *capture* what you need to skip and add an alternative to what you need to *replace*. However, your regex is not suitable since it will match the whole `{{{a}}` as the first `\{\{` will match the first `{{` in the string. You need to replace the lazy dot matching with a negated character class `[^{}]*` to only match 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`.

Then just use `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String s = "{{{abc}}";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\{[^{}]*}})|[{}]").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1));
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, "\\\\" + m.group());
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString()); // Demo output.
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Gxhz4J)

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

```
\{\{[^{}]+\}\}
```